# python docx library failed to install

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to install docx library but encountering following error:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /TcC:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitm8atyno6.c /FoUsers\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitm8atyno6.obj
      xmlXPathInitm8atyno6.c
      C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitm8atyno6.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory        
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Successfully built docx
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, docx
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [91 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
      running install
      C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is 
deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\lxml
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -IC:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
      etree.c
      C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-adq4u3we\lxml_c6625f42221d4ee2b0812fceb88aa286\src\lxml\includes/etree_defs.h(14): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h': No such file or directory
      Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /TcC:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitxhzkhkzy.c /FoUsers\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitxhzkhkzy.obj
      xmlXPathInitxhzkhkzy.c
      C:\Users\Ideapad\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInitxhzkhkzy.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory        
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have tried following steps:

1. Restoring windows
2. Upgrading vsbuildtools
3. pip install -u setuptools
4. pip install wheel
5. Downloading libxml2 and listing it in environment variables directory.

But none of the above methods seems to work. How can I solve this issue any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I tried downloading and installing lxml too from https://github.com/lxml/lxml/pull/356#issuecomment-1324905890 and it shows following error.  \nS C:\Windows> pip install lxml-4.9.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'lxml-4.9.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\windows\lxml-4.9.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Exception:\n Though the file is present in x:\Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my issue was resolved I downloaded lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml), placed it in "c:\windows" and installed using `pip install lxml-4.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.`